# NodeJS - get property for Mongodb not working while connecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to NodeJS and ExpressJS. I am following this tutorial http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/  for creating and connecting mongodb with nodejs. Everything works perfectly(DB data inserting through command line,package.json config) except db connection, it throws `undefined error`.

```
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/deno');
```

I check this in console like this `console.log(db)` it shows `'undefined'` in `index.js`

My app.js is :

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// New Code
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/Fujitsu');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Make our db accessible to our router
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.db = db;
    next();
});


app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

routes/index.js is

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

/************ Customized starts Here **********/

/* GET Userlist page. */

router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {

    var db = req.db; 
    console.log(db);
    var collection = db.get('usercollection');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('userlist', {
            "userlist" : docs
        });
    });
});



/******** Customized - Ends here ***********/

module.exports = router;
```

Please anyone of you tell me the solution because now I'm struggling with this.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: few things: 
what is your node version? 
please tell what is the print of `console.log(db)` after this line `var db = monk('localhost:27017/Fujitsu');` in your `app.js`

Comment: I mean just put the `console.log(db)` after this line `var db = monk('localhost:27017/Fujitsu');`, run the app and post the outcome here

Comment: are u running mongodb? if you are on Unix-like OS just run this command in your terminal `mongod`
if you are on Windows, run this guy `C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe` or rather switch to Linux

Comment: app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users); - You app.js isn't same compared to that tutorial. Where is this

Comment: You have made a collection with the name Fijitsu right?

Comment: You app.js isn't the exact replica of what it is given in the Tutorial though. Can you please update the question with error. Just copy it from the console

Comment: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at D:\node\Fujitsu\routes\index.js:23:24
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\node\Fujitsu\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (...

Comment: I replicate from the tutorial. Same error!! @GandalftheWhite

Comment: what is at line 23 & 24 of your index.js

Comment: at routes/index.js -->  var db = req.db; 
    console.log(db);
    var collection = db.get('usercollection');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('userlist', {
            "userlist" : docs
        });

Comment: are you sure that usercollection named collection there. In the tutorial usercollection named collection was created.